# How do you use the sync function in a multi dimensional array in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Can u use the sync method in laravel to sync this type of a multi dimensional array?

```
array:19 [▼
  "_token" => "r87fqYAVFkBIIYth9dvc6i9zxI73PkBztu3KdJ6f"
  "_method" => "PATCH"
  "role" => "teacher"
  "last_name" => "Maya"
  "name" => "Vusumzi"
  "email" => "maya.vusumzi@gmail.com"
  "phone" => "0719087970"
  "gender" => "Male"
  "identity" => "8548976907564"
  "old_password" => null
  "new_password" => null
  "new_password_confirmation" => null
  "street" => "30 Sabalele street,"
  "suburb" => "Motherwell NU4B"
  "city" => "Port Elizabeth"
  "province" => "Eastern Cape"
  "code" => "6211"
  "grade" => array:5 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
    2 => "3"
    3 => "4"
    4 => "5"
  ]
  "subjects" => array:5 [▼
    1 => array:2 [▼
      0 => "1"
      1 => "2"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
      0 => "1"
      1 => "5"
    ]
    3 => array:3 [▼
      0 => "1"
      1 => "5"
      2 => "6"
    ]
    4 => array:2 [▼
      0 => "1"
      1 => "3"
    ]
    5 => array:4 [▼
      0 => "1"
      1 => "4"
      2 => "5"
      3 => "6"
    ]
  ]
]
```

I want to sync the subjects' array in this controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {  
       
        $user = User::where('id',$id)->first();
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
        
        $user->grades()->sync($request->grade);
        
        if($request->subjects){ 
            $user->subjects()->sync($request->subjects);
        }

        return redirect()->back()->with('message', $user->name . ' is updated Successfully');

    }
```

The grade is working fine but the issue is the subjects array, its giving me this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update grade_subject set 0 = 1 where grade_id = 1 and subject_id in (1))

this is what is sent to the controller update method

```
@foreach($classes as $key => $class)
                    <div class="card shadow mx-2 my-4">
                        <div class="card-header bg-light py-3">
                            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold">
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox"  id="{{$class->id}}" name="grade[]" value="{{ $class->id }}" 
                                    {{ ($user->grades->pluck('id')->contains($class->id)) ? 'checked' : '' }} />
                                    <label class="custom-control-label pt-1" for="{{$class->id}}">{{$class->name}}</label>
                                </div>
                            </h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">                      
                            @foreach($class->subjects as $key => $subject)
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mt-2">
                                

                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input @error('subjects') is-invalid @enderror" id="{{$class->id}}{{$subject->id}}" 
                                name="subjects[{{$class->id}}][]" value="{{ $subject->id }}" 
                                {{ ($user->grades->pluck('id')->contains($class->id) && $user->subjects->pluck('id')->contains($subject->id)) ? 'checked': ''}}/>



                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{$class->id}}{{$subject->id}}">{{$subject->name}}</label>
                            </div>   
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
```

Comment: what are the arrays in `subjects` supposed to represent individually?

Comment: They represent the Ids of the subjects in a particular grade id

Comment: so that is grade 1 through 5's subjects?

Comment: @lagbox Yes that is correct